# Action page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How do i create a page like an action page in php, in C# ?To be specific I only require a page that contains only methods that handle various operations and return result.

How do i solve the above scenario ?

Comment: You can accomplish that by using a class in the application, and referring to an instance of that class.

Comment: I think http handlers  what you are looking for, you may not need this though.

Comment: From where do you want to call those methods? From other server-side code, or from client-side HTML?

Comment: I want to do it on my server side code..

Comment: @user256103 : i need an action page like one in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [HttpHandlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

For example, you want to have a method that returns a json string in a web forms application.

Add a new item to your project of type "Generic Handler". This will create a new .ashx file. The main method of any class that implements IHttpHandler is ProcessRequest.

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["day"]))
    {
        context.Response.End(); 
    }

    string json = "";
    byte[] bytes = getByteArray();

    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bytes);
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
    context.Response.Write(json);
}
```

Change the url in your AJAX call and that should do it. The JavaScript would look like this , where GetFileHandler.ashx is the name of the IHttpHandler you just created:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: 'Handlers/GetFileHandler.ashx',
        data: "Day=" + $.toJSON(day),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log("SUCCESS:" + msg);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log("error:" + msg);
        }
    });
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072745/how-to-return-a-json-object-in-standard-web-forms-net) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class, then inside the class create your methods to construct the logic behind your application.

Then reference this class with the using keyword in your web pages and use the methods you created wherever you like.