# return json from pageload in asp.net + populate other data

Tags: asp.net, json

I have an aspx page - and on the page load I need to populate field with information (the regular way - txt1.Text ="abc" etc).
But, I also need to return a json object in order to use it on the $(document).ready(...)

Can I return those 2 type of information on the page_load? and how?

- I can't use ajax after page load - I need all the information to be load with the page_load

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can, Great discussion about it already on [stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072745/how-to-return-a-json-object-in-standard-web-forms-net

Comment: @Yuri good catch that thread has everything you would need in greater depth then I presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an ajax call on the dom ready to the server to get your json data. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ you would need a service to hit from your ajax request to pull your json data back to render it on the page. There are a few options in asp.net including .ashx handlers, web methods https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx, and others.

Answer (score 1):

Store your JSON string in a `HiddenField`, then read and parse it in the `ready` handler.

C#:

```
JsonField.Value = myJsonString;
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    var json = $("#<%=JsonField.ClientID%>").val();
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
});
```

Comment: I just tested with a 200MB string and didn't have any trouble.  I don't believe there's a limit.  Is your JSON string longer than 200MB?