# How to pass the text field value to C# page using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to pass the parameter to another page using ajax.Actually i have one popup dialog box,in that dialog box i have one text field,i have to send that value to another page to save into db.not getting how to do it.
Here is my code

```
$(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#popup").dialog({
            title: "Add",
            width: 430,
            height: 250,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Add: function() {
                    var t = ($('#user').val());
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Details.aspx.cs/getData",
                        data: {
                            "test1": t
                        },
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });

                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? The code looks good

Comment: i want to pass the t value into getData method.not getting how to get it in that method in Details.aspx.cs page.

Answer (score 0):

You are not transferring the data correct. if you want to do it this way, you have you use JSON.stringify of JSON.parse.

You can also try to use

```
 data: "{'test':'" +  t+ "'}",
```

or something of this sort, I used to do it in the past, but don't have the example in front of my eyes now. Will have it clearly later on though.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call seems fine. There could be a possibility that the json string is not formed correctly from the textbox javascript value. try using JSON.stringify:

```
function() {
    var t = ($('#user').val().trim());
    var payload = { "test1" : t };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Details.aspx.cs/getData",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
});
```

Comment: In Details.aspx.cs page how to get the passing value?please help me

Comment: it's not alerting the data

Comment: not sure in web forms but in mvc you would do something like ; public JsonResult getData(string test1){..........}

Comment: this might help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072745/how-to-return-a-json-object-in-standard-web-forms-net