# how to change Console App output result only not whole html

Tags: c#, html, console-application

When I run my Html code it only display **`JSON`** result but if I use console to call the `http` it display the whole code of the web form.  What can I change to make it only display the **`JSON`** result on console app?

**[Html Code]**

[image]

**[console result]**

[image]

```
        using (var client = new WebClient()) //WebClient  
        {
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");
            var result = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:49299/test.aspx");  
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: I think the returned result is not application/json. It is text/html. Need to make sure the server return truly application/json. Dont have server code so not sure what happen here

Comment: i have update the 1st pic become html code

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the whole web page response, which includes all the HTML and the JavaScript.

Apparently, what you want is the result of a JavaScript function that is being run on the page by the browser. They way I would solve that is by letting the JavaScript do a XHR call back to the server containing the result.

Since you are using ASP.NET you could set up a ASP.NET Web API project to respond to such REST calls.

Comment: Any other way to do it ? just editing on old codes.  i have edit the pic 1 become html codes .

Comment: @Avivi I have a hard time understanding how it ever could have worked. The JavaScript, to report the geolocation, needs to be run on the client. Downloading the content of the page in C# will just download the code, it can't run the code on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Your server code just only return html that contain javascript. If you request to the server by a web browser, the browser will execute javascript and you see the right data. Meanwhile, if you make requests by C# code, javascript will not be executed. So you need to know

1. How asp.net webforms return json data here [How to return a JSON object in standard web forms .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072745/how-to-return-a-json-object-in-standard-web-forms-net)
2. How to consume google geocoder api by C#. You can manually request to google api by C# or just utilize a wrapper. May be this https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net. I have not yet tried this before