# How to display dynamic server side data retrieved from client side using AJAX method in a Javascript Pie Chart, in a html template (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, ajax

I have successfully managed to retrieve data from Client Side (C# Back End) to Server Side (Javascript HTML in aspx) using AJAX. Since the example given by the internet uses a  inside a  to display data, im unsure how i should display my own data dynamically into the Javascript Pie Chart.

[This shows the AJAX method in the aspx form, by using POST method to retrieve data from the C# method "calculateAverageLoginRate"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h6wb.png)

[This is the c# method "calculateAverageLoginRate"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ho4K.png)

[This is the result that is displays in an empty web form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CexIE.png)

[This is the original script for the Pie Chart inside the aspx. Note that the value has been hardcoded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tGWH.png)

I want to replace the hardcoded values in the piechart with my own dynamic data retrieved from my c# method "calculateAverageLoginRate". Since im using AJAX, im unfamiliar with how AJAX should be coded such that it is able to take the retrieved data, and input it as a piechart value. Please advice, thank you.

Comment: Do you want the color to be hardcoded? Or dynamic from DB?
Please don't post your coded as pics, type them in your description instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are in the right track. Change your success function to below, declare `pieData` globally. In your success function you assign the response to the `pieData` array. Your function only returns a single number - so you can just assign it straight away.

```
//declare globally
var pieData;


   // change success function to this
        success: function(response) {
            pieData = [
                {
                    value: response, //response is from ajax request
                    color: "#337AB7" //hardcoded color
                },
                { //hardcoded object
                    value: 50,
                    color: "#FC8213"
                }
            ];
            //instantiate chart
            new Chart(document.getElementById("pie").getcontext("2d").Pie(pideData));
        }
```

---

**BUT** in the event it returns an array in JSON format, you can iterate it like so:

Json (example):

```
[
    {
        value: 'some random value1', 
        color: "#353AB7" 
    },
    {
        value: 'some random value2', 
        color: "#237AB7" 
    },
    {
        value: 'some random value3', 
        color: "#F37AB7" 
    },
    {
        value: 'some random value14, 
        color: "#137AB7" 
    }
]
```

Js:

```
// declare global array
var pieData = [];

// change success function to this
success: function(response) {
     response.forEach(function(el) {
         pieData.push({value: el.value, color: el.color})
     });

    new Chart(document.getElementById("pie").getcontext("2d").Pie(pideData));
}
```

Comment: it worked! But how can i return multiple values from my function?

Comment: ..1 It's good etiquette in SO to vote or accept the answer if it did help.
I'm not too familiar with ASP NET **BUT** what I can recommend you is change the return type of your function to a `string` so you can return JSON. What you're doing now is returning a `decimal` which is only a single value. Inside the function you can iterate each value you're calculating and construct an object. Then return that object as JSON. Read these for references; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072745/how-to-return-a-json-object-in-standard-web-forms-net

Comment: Sorry im a student and i rarely post questions, so im new. Thank you for answering my question